# How to disable drag in swiper slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I am using swiper slider version 3.3.1.
I did apply this code, but not working

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    speed: 400,
    autoHeight: false,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: 2500,
    autoplayStopOnLast: false, 
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationType: "bullets",
    simulateTouch:false, 
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    effect: 'fade',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    scrollbar: {
     container: '.swiper-scrollbar',
     draggable: false,
   }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I think it should be

```
allowTouchMove: false
```

Comment: Instead of what?

Comment: Just add it to your swiper settings.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto Veronica's answer, you can set `allowTouchMove: false` as a parameter for the Swiper.

**Example in React:**

```
<Swiper
  allowTouchMove={false} // disable touch / drag swiping
  {...swiperProps}
>
  {...slides}
</Swiper>
```

You can read more in the [Swiper Documentation](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-allowTouchMove)